# How can I print out the delimiter character and allow user to edit line while reading standard input?

Tags: bash, readline, read

I'm trying to write a simple script that read from standard input, using  `;`  character as delimiter to terminate the input line and that allows user to edit line.

Here is my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  read -e -d ";" -t 180 -p "><> " srcCommand

  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "end;"
    echo ""
    exit 0
  fi
  case "$srcCommand" in
    startApp)
       echo "startApp command";;
    stopApp)
       echo "stopApp command";;
    end)
       echo ""
       exit 0
       ;;
    *)
       echo "unknown command";;
  esac
done
```

This works but doesn't print the delimiter ';' char:

```
# bash test.sh
><> startApp
startApp command
><> stopApp
stopApp command
><> end
```

If I remove -e option it prints out  `;`  but user can't correct his mistake using backspace character and echoed strings are just right after the delimiter:

```
# bash test.sh
><> startApp;startApp command
><> stopApp;stopApp command
><> end;
```

How can I print out the delimiter character and allow user to edit line while reading standard input?

This is the expected behavior:

```
# bash test.sh
><> startApp;
startApp command
><> stopApp;
stopApp command
><> end;
```

Thanks

Comment: I think `-i` option would work for you.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value/6703730#6703730

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks, but this is not useful in this case, if I add `-i ";"` together with `-e` option, read command puts text into the editing buffer before editing begins, and I get:  `><> ;startApp` end test.sh script doesn't recognize any command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `zsh` where the line editor has many more capabilities and is a lot more customizable:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
insert-and-accept() {
  zle self-insert
  # RBUFFER= # to discard everything on the right
  zle accept-line
}
zle -N insert-and-accept
bindkey ";" insert-and-accept
bindkey "^M" self-insert
vared -p "><> " -c srcCommand
```

With `bash-4.3` or above, you can do something similar with a hack like:

```
# bind ; to ^Z^C (^Z, ^C otherwide bypass the key binding when entered
# on the keyboard). Redirect stderr to /dev/null to discard the
# useless warning
bind '";":"\32\3"' 2> /dev/null

# new widget that inserts ";" at the end of the buffer.
# If we did bind '";":";\3"', readline would loop indefinitely
add_semicolon() {
  READLINE_LINE+=";"
  ((READLINE_POINT++))
}
# which we bind to ^Z
bind -x '"\32":add_semicolon' 2> /dev/null

# read until the ^C
read -e -d $'\3' -t 180 -p '><> ' srcCommand
```

Note that in that version, the `;` is always inserted at the end of the input buffer, not at the current cursor position. Change the `add_semicolon` to:

```
add_semicolon() {
  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:READLINE_POINT++};"
}
```

If you want it inserted at the cursor and everything on the right discarded. Or:

```
add_semicolon() {
  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:READLINE_POINT};${READLINE_LINE:READLINE_POINT}"
  READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
}
```

if you want to insert it at the cursor but want to preserve what's on the right like in the `zsh` approach.

If you don't want the `;` in `$srcCommand`, you can always strip it afterwards with `srcCommand="${srcComman//;}"` for instance, but you'd need to insert it in the widget for it to be displayed by `zle`/`readline`.

Comment: I'll use add_semicolon that inserts at the cursor and discards everything on the right. thanks a lot this was exactly what I was looking for and even more!

Comment: Do you know how I would use a list of keys or a variable in place of `"\32"` in the `bind -x` command?